# If Function isn't working properly

Tags: function, excel-formula, excel-2010

I'm trying to pull out only Salary Earnings from a Payroll tab to "Salary Earnings" column on Unique payroll tab using this "IF" function: `=IF(Payroll!F2="Salary", Payroll!G2, " ")` but for some reason it's skipping the salary on the same date as bonus.

[image: Payroll Tab]
[image: Unique Payroll]

I even tried the below one, and it's leaving D5, D6, and D7 empty.

```
=IF(AND(Payroll!F2="Salary", Payroll!C2=UniquePayPeriod!C2), Payroll!G2, " ")
```

Can anyone help please? 
Thanks!

Comment: Which formula do you have in Cell D5 of the second table? And in cell D6?

Comment: I have "IF" function: =IF(Payroll!F2="Salary", Payroll!G2, " ")

Comment: In cell D5???? What's the logic behind that? What does cell D5 have to do with Payroll!F2 ?

Comment: @JohnB I was assuming "Bonus" on F5 of Payroll would be omitted and jumps to the next one where there's "Salary" and give me the G6 as a result on D5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I assume you're dragging the formula down in your `UniquePayPeriod` spreadsheet, then you may not be getting the "right" output, but you're getting the "accurate" output.

1. D5 will be blank because F5 is "Bonus", failing your if condition
2. D6 will be blank because `Payroll!C6` is not equal to `UniquePayPeriod!C6`
3. D7 will be blank because `Payroll!C7` is not equal to `UniquePayPeriod!C7`

This is happening because your `Payroll` sheet is listing Bonuses on separate line items with the same dates; after the first listing of a bonus, your Check Dates on your `UniquePayPeriod` sheet will not align with your Check Dates on the `Payroll` sheet

What you'll need to do is use `Match` and `Index` to look up the condition of ID, Check Date, and Salary, and then ID, Check Date, and Bonus.

This is the formula you need to put in your Salary Earnings Column

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(yourPayrollTable,MATCH(B2&C2&"Salary",yourIDColumn & 
                   yourCheckDateColumn & yourEarnTypeColumn,0),7),"")
```

This is the formula you need to put in your Salary Earnings Column

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(yourPayrollTable,MATCH(B2&C2&"Bonus",yourIDColumn & 
                   yourCheckDateColumn & yourEarnTypeColumn,0),7),"")
```

- `yourPayrollTable` should be the range of data on the `Payroll` sheet
  that has all your payroll information (`Payroll!A2:G100` for example)
- `yourIDColumn` should be the range of data on the `Payroll` sheet
  that has all the IDs (`Payroll!A2:A100` for example)
- `yourCheckDateColumn` should be the range of data on the `Payroll` sheet
  that has all the Check Dates (`Payroll!C2:C100` for example)
- `yourEarnTypeColumn` should be the range of data on the `Payroll` sheet
  that has all the Earn Types (`Payroll!F2:F100` for example)

These formulas are Array Formulas, so please make sure you press Ctrl+Shift+Enter after entering the formula and dragging it down, instead of just pressing Enter.

This can be a bit confusing so please comment if it does not make sense what you need to do

Comment: Thank you! It works and makes sense but it's showing an errors with "Formula Omits adjacent cells" and "Ignore error" in the green drop down list of the left upper corner tiny triangle of the resulted cells. And also somehow it didn't work for Bonus earnings, but I can try it again.

Comment: You can ignore those formulas by selecting all the cells with the green arrow, then selecting ignore error for the top cell. Make sure than in the "Bonus" column of your UniquePayroll Sheet, makes sure the cell values are still referring to Column B and C (B2 and C2 and not C2 and D2)

Comment: Glad it was helpful for you! you can "accept" this answer by clicking the check next to it